# How to make a server call (PHP) using axios (react-redux) from localhost (using express server)?

Tags: php, reactjs, express, webpack, react-redux

I'm new to React. I have a button in one of the components, on clicking the button, a server side (PHP) call should be made using axios GET call and the response should change the state of the store.

I have set the app using webpack and using the express server.
What changes to their settings be made in order to run PHP code?

Comment: So, which part is it you're having issues with? Your PHP code or your JS code?

Comment: So do you want to serve your static files through express and have a php server running in parallel that exposes some api endpoints?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson PHP code

Comment: @trixn yes, so that I can add PHP code, and be able to make GET or POST calls using axios.

Answer (score 0):

> I have set the app using webpack and using the express server. What changes to their settings be made in order to run PHP code?

You don't have to change any settings there. These tools can't run PHP code. If you want to serve your static files (`.html`, `.css`, `.js`) with express you can leave that as it is. But you have to run another local webserver next to express that can run PHP code and that listens on another port. `PHP 5.4+` has a built-in development server. Or you can use `nginx` or `apache`.

You could use e.g. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#installation) which is a popular web application framework. This makes it easy to run a local development server and to define a RESTful api which you will need to provide in order to communicate with your react app. Laravel uses the built-in PHP web server. When you installed Laravel you can start it with:

```
php artisan serve
```

This command will start a development server at `http://localhost:8000`. Express is per default running at `http://localhost:3000`.

Then you can define a [REST api in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) and send requests to it.

Of course you can use other PHP frameworks too if you don't want to use Laravel.